# NDSolve with piecewise function gives error "Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at x == 0."

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages, piecewise

I am solving differential equation with piecewise function and i am getting error that NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at `x == 0.`. >>.... my code is below...

```
NDSolve[{y'[x] == d[x] - f[x] + y[x] - Exp[-y[x]] + 1, y[0] == 0}, 
 y[x], {x, 0, 14}]
f[x_] := \[Piecewise] {
   {Tanh[2 x], 0 < x < 2},
   {Tanh[-2 (x - 4)], 2 < x < 6},
   {Tanh[2 (x - 8)], 6 < x < 10},
   {Tanh[-2 (x - 12)], 10 < x < 14}
  }
d = f'[x]
Plot[d, {x, 0, 14}]
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 14}, PlotRange -> {{0, 14}, {-2, 2}}]
```

Comment: There are some syntax errors. [Piecewise] is incorrect syntax. What do you mean by d[x] and d = f'[x] ?

Comment: @Lotus, that was the SE site messing up the pasted code.  If you paste something like `\[Piecewise]` without enclosing it in code markup, it only shows the [ bracket and not the \ slash

Comment: Note that `f'[0]` is `Indeterminate`, i.e. a non-numerical value, hence so is `y'[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your `f` function is undefined at the boundaries between regions, so use `<=` to make sure the whole range is covered

```
f[x_] := \[Piecewise]{{Tanh[2 x], 0 <= x < 2}, {Tanh[-2 (x - 4)], 
     2 <= x < 6}, {Tanh[2 (x - 8)], 6 <= x < 10}, {Tanh[-2 (x - 12)], 
     10 <= x <= 14}};
d = f';
```

Second, when you try to take the derivative at a boundary, you find that you get an error,

```
d[2]
(* Indeterminate *)
```

But from the plots it is clear the first derivative is continuous,

```
Grid[{{Plot[d[x], {x, 0, 14}],
   Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 14}, PlotRange -> {{0, 14}, {-2, 2}}]}}]
```

[image]

So define an auxiliary function that takes the limit of the derivative,

```
g[x_] := Limit[d[xp], xp -> x]
g[2]
(* -2 Sech[4]^2 *)
```

Now you can call `NDSolve` without error,

```
NDSolve[{y'[x] == g[x] - f[x] + y[x] - Exp[-y[x]] + 1, 
  y[0] == 0}, y, {x, 0, 14}]
(* {{y -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 14.}}, <>]}} *)
```

and plot the result,

```
Plot[y[x] /. %, {x, 0.10, 14}]
```

[image]

Comment: no its does not work

Comment: in what way does it not work?